# Non-Standard Deviation

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

Given a list of integers, how to find the sum of the differences of all possible pairs of numbers ?

For example if the number are $3,1,2$ then, answer should be $$\lvert 3-1 \rvert + \lvert 3 -2 \rvert + \lvert 1-2 \rvert
= 2 + 1 + 1
= 4 $$

Suggest a suitable algorithm for this.

Comment: This is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ times [Gini's mean difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_difference)

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting the numbers and see if it helps.

Comment: I did tried that but not getting any ideas for the next :(

Comment: Hint: if $a > b$ then $|a-b| = a-b$; if $a < b$ then $|a-b| = b-a$.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "suitable"?  There is the simple approach of looping over all pairs, taking the absolute value of the difference, and accumulating.  This is O(n^2).  Do you think there is something better?  As Yuval suggests, you can sort to avoid the absolute value.

Comment: Yes, there is something better. Yuval's suggestion wasn't just about avoiding the absolute value.

Comment: Indeed - you can take a weighted sum of the sorted values, where the weight is a simple function of the ranks and the number of values: for example $4 = 3 + 3 - 1 - 1$.

Comment: @Henry:  thanks.  got it